# Python - Old pandas merge results in more rows than new pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 environments:

**Environment #1:**

- Python 3.7.5
- Pandas 0.23.4

**Environment #2:**

- Python 3.8.10
- Pandas 1.3.4

I have the same code in both versions, no modifications were made to it. However, I have this specific line of code which seems to be causing an issue/produces a different output:

`df_result = pd.merge(df_l, df_r, left_on=left_on, right_on=right_on, how='inner', suffixes=suffixes)`

`df_l` and `df_r` are just read Excel files. I checked them in debugger in both versions and they are completely the same, so that should be fine.
Also, the `left_on`, `right_on` and `suffixes` variables have exactly the same value in both environments (checked via debugger, as well).

However, when the `df_result` gets generated by the `merge` function, in environment #1 (old Python, old Pandas) it produces a DataFrame with 16170 rows. In environment #2 (new Python, new Pandas) it produces a DataFrame with only 8249 rows.
The number of columns are the same, difference is only in number of rows.

What is causing this behavior?

How do I make sure that the environment #2 (new Python, new Pandas) produces exactly the same output with 16170 rows as produced by environment #1 (old Python, old Pandas)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the issue lied within new Pandas' approach to handle `NaN` values.
While in the old Pandas the code changed the `NaN` values with `<NA>` (as string), in the new Pandas it just left it as `nan` (`pd.nan` type).

I made sure to do `df.fillna('<NA>', inplace=True)` and it worked fine. The resulted DataFrame now has the same number of rows as produced by the old Pandas.

Comment: you can mark your answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote it.